# Override font-face definition

Tags: css, font-face, font-family

Supposing that there is a font-face definition in a file which I have no access, is  it possible to override from a global CSS file?

For instance, in one file (non-accesible file) there is the following definition:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'openSans-Bold';
    src: url('OpenSans-Bold-webfont.eot');
    src: url('OpenSans-Bold-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('OpenSans-Bold-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
         url('OpenSans-Bold-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('OpenSans-Bold-webfont.svg#openSans-Bold') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

I have tried to override as follows in another global file (using the same name):

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'openSans-Bold' !important;
  src: local('Arial') !important;
  font-weight: 700 !important;
  font-style: normal !important;
}
```

But sadly it's not working.

Answer (score 1):

You can't override the font-face itself.
I suggest you may change the font-family using JavaScript.

if this is the main font-family for your template you may change it for the body :

```
document.body.style.fontFamily = 'Arial';
```

or you select the elements with this specific font-family.

https://jsfiddle.net/a73ekh6z/

Answer (score 1):

Css rules defined using '@' symbol can't be used for cascading or overriding styles.

The best possible way to override the font-family in your case would be using js/jquery.

**js:**

```
document.body.style.fontFamily = 'Arial';
```

**jquery:**

```
$('body').css("font-family", $(this).val());
```